# JavaScript functions with ajax do not execute one after other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I recently noticed the below behavior of my code.

```
    function abc(){
        a();
        b();
        c();
    }
    function a(){
        // ajax call
        $("#number").val("a");
        // ajax call finished
    }
    function b(){
        // ajax call
        $("#number").val("b");
        // ajax call finished 
    }
    function c(){
        alert($("#number").val());
        // ajax call
        $("#number").val("c");
        // ajax call finished
    }
```

HTML code

```
<input id="number"  value=""  type="hidden"/>

<button type="submit" id="mySubmit" onClick="abc()">Search</button>
```

I thought when I call function `abc()` then first `a()` will execute and then `b()` and then `c()`

But it appears to me that `alert` in `c()` is executes before `b()` finishes because it shows `a` as the alert box result.

But if the code is like below it works as expected, (alert shows `b`)

```
    function abc(){
        a();
        b();
        c();
    }
    function a(){
        $("#number").val("a");
    }
    function b(){
        $("#number").val("b");
    }
    function c(){
        alert($("#number").val());
        $("#number").val("c");
    }
```

**Why is this happening ? Is those ajax calls in the first code have something to do with this ?**

Note: sorry I could not recreate this problem in a fiddle. someone with this kind of experience and know the reason can help me with this.

And I've posted [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28392546/what-happens-if-call-two-functions-when-button-click-event-in-javascript) as well. Those answers contradict this behavior.

Comment: ajax: "Perform an **asynchronous** HTTP (Ajax) request."

Comment: http://blog.slaks.net/2015-01-04/async-method-patterns/

Comment: @Tomanow : please can you elaborate your answer.

Comment: @prime This is the fundamental concept of JavaScript. It doesn't care when anything is completed, it just runs what it can in any order that suits itself. Use a search engine to read more about it.

Comment: [asynchronous](https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=asynchronous&gws_rd=ssl): "(of two or more objects or events) not existing or happening at the same time."

Comment: @Jonast92 either I totally misunderstand what you're saying or your statement borders on mere hearsay.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the nature of Ajax calls.  When you make asynchronous calls, they are considered "done" once the call is initialized, not when the call finishes.  Therefore it'll keep moving along without waiting.

If you want to make the calls in this order, you can do a couple of things:

1. Make b() and c() callbacks in your call to a() - This means you wait until a() is finished and in the .done() part of your call, you can call the other functions
2. If you're using jQuery, you can specify that you want the call to not be asynchronous (async: false) - See here for more info: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

Your function will call a() b() and c() in order, but you can't handle the order of the responses for each ajax call, so for this reason they can appear to be unsorted.